# MonoDevelop Command line debugger

Tags: mono, monodevelop, unity-game-engine

Where is the command line debugger for Monodevelop? I'm using unity's version (3.5) of mono version 2.10? I'm using OSX

I'm trying to find the mdb talked about here: http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:Debugger

I didn't see it in here /Applications/Unity/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS

Answer (score 1):

The mdb debugger is dead and no longer developed. It likely won't even work with your version of Mono.

The only debugger for Mono currently is the one built into MonoDevelop.

Comment: This is the closet thing I could find but the attach functionality doesn't work. https://github.com/alexrp/sdb-cli

Comment: Alex is working on that, but it's still under development as you've noticed.